# Make the UIRefreshControl short for swiping

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, swipe, uirefreshcontrol

When using the standard `UIRefreshControl` in `TableView` the swipe down can be too long, that is, I have to drag my finger almost to the very bottom of the screen.

Is it possible to shorten the swipe path?

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

 @objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // Refresh anything
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    TableView.addSubview(refreshControl) 
    
    refresh(view)
 }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.

```
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshHande(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    let ori = tableView.frame
    let temp_frame = CGRect.init(x: ori.origin.x, y: ori.origin.y, width:
    ori.size.width, height: ori.size.height/1.3 )
    tableView.frame = temp_frame
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    tableView.frame = ori
```

Answer (score 0):

TableView has property **refreshControl**. Use the following code

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

 @objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // Refresh anything
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    // tableView is a UITableView outlet 
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    
 }
```